# ⌥ +⇧ + 7 (backslash on Swedish keyboard) crashes programs on macOS High Sierra

Tags: keyboard, crash

*Using macOS 10.13.4*

I'm using the swedish keyboard layout on my iMac, and I've got a problem with my keyboard. Everytime I press "⌥ +⇧ + 7" the active program (some programs crashes after pressing it 2 times) will crash. May it be, "Terminal", "Messages", "Chrome" or whatever..

For example, in Terminal, first time I press it, it will open help, second time, it will crash the terminal with this stacktrace:

```
Application Specific Information:

objc_msgSend() selector name: deselectAll:

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                0x00007fff58c05e9d objc_msgSend + 29
1   com.apple.shortcut            0x00007fff528fc4d9 -[SCTSearchManager performSearch] + 43
2   com.apple.shortcut            0x00007fff528f9456 SCTHelpMenuHandler + 750
3   com.apple.HIToolbox            0x00007fff307d4904 DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 1541
```

If I press the same combination in Messages, I get the same. If I do it in Chrome however it's a different error. But Chrome still crashes, with with another stacktrace. I just want to write backslashes. Any help how to debug this issue?

Stacktrace when pressing it in Chrome:

```
Application Specific Information:
Crashing on exception: -[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000000583c0

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3159932b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   Google Chrome Framework             0x00000001070486a1 ChromeMain + 30804705
2   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff58c13c76 objc_exception_throw + 48
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff31631e04 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3150f870 ___forwarding___ + 1456
5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3150f238 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
6   Foundation                          0x00007fff335f7c82 NSSelectorFromString + 66
```

I can write backslashes just fine with English keyboard-layout.

Comment: What version of MacOS are you talking about??

Comment: I will double-check tomorrow, but pretty sure its 10.13.4.